# Git clone works with SSH but not HTTP

Tags: git

I have a public repo on a server (apache), I can clone it with SSH from local with :

```
$ git clone user@myserver:public_html/repo
```

But the same repo can't be cloned with http :

```
$ git clone http://myserver/repo 
// fatal: repository 'http://myserver/repo' not found
```

With a browser I can see the content of my repo when entering (userdir mod is activated and set to be document root) :

```
http://myserver/repo
```

and the associated git folder with

```
http://myserver/repo/.git
```

I set the folder permission to 755.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Which git server are you using? Just be exposing the git repository/files over http(s) is not enough to make it work over http.

Comment: Have you tried Git HTTP Smart Device?  Or if it falls back to Dumb HTTP put a bare Git repository under your HTTP document root and set up a specific post-update hook, and you’re done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git clone https://username@myserver.com/repo/.git
```

or the insecure version:

```
git clone https://username:password@myserver.com/repo/.git
```

Also make sure you are using the latest version of Git.